# Can you change the from number when sending SMS text during a call?

Tags: twilio

Twillio allows you to send SMS during an outgoing call with  tag in twiML script.  However, while outgoing calls' "from number" can be any verified number, sms text must be from Twillio's number.  This is causing some SMS to not be sent if the call was initiated from a verified, but non-Twillio number.  My question is what is the best way to change the from number of SMS message, so that it won't get dropped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

The `<Sms>` verb lets you specify To and From parameters on it, so you could set the From to be a Twilio phone number.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms#attributes-from

Hope that helps.